# jQuery accordion does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, accordion

i think i have done all right but still accordion is not working

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="assets/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Acc").accordion();
</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div  id="Acc">
    <h3>First One</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            1st Data
        </p>
    </div>
     <h3>second One</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
           2nd Data
        </p>
    </div>
     <h3>Third One</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            3rd Data
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the script in `document.ready` which delays the execution of a script until the DOM is completely loaded.  Currently the script cannot find the `div#Acc` when it executes because it has not been loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Acc").accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be within a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("#Acc").accordion();
})
```

Since your script is in the header when your selector `$("#Acc")` is executed, the element is not yet loaded to the dom so the selector will not return anything thus the accordion widget will not get initiated for the element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/amrL6/)